# How to remove a string selectively from pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, string, jupyter-notebook

I am having some hard time to get rid of a string from my pandas series. I'd like to remove the first two '-' strings but want to keep the last two number objectives. Example is below.

```
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.Series(['-', '-', '-0.3', '-0.9'])
print(temp)

Out[135]: 
0       -
1       -
2    -0.3
3    -0.9
dtype: object
```

Can't use `temp.str.replace("-", "")` since it removes the minus sign from the last two number objectives as well. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use regex to have more control over how to replace text: `temp.str.replace(r'-$', '')` will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
temp = pd.Series(['-', '-', '-0.3', '-0.9'])
print(temp.str.replace('^-$',  '', regex=True))
```

**Output**

```
0        
1        
2    -0.3
3    -0.9
dtype: object
```

Or simply use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
print(temp.replace('-',  ''))  # notice that there is no .str
```

**Output**

```
0        
1        
2    -0.3
3    -0.9
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert strings to numbers:

```
pd.to_numeric(temp, errors='coerce').fillna('')
```

Output:

```
0
1
2   -0.3
3   -0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the unwanted string's like this:

```
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.Series(['-', '-', '-0.3', '-0.9'])

# this will drop the string that match '-'
new_temp= temp[temp != '-']

print(new_temp)
```

**Output:**

```
2    -0.3
3    -0.9
dtype: object
```

reference: [Here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows/)